# C# Windows Service Email Issue

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, service, smtp

I have a Windows Service that runs on a schedule (timer). Every 10 minutes the service calls a method that is exposed via a WCF Service in my main website.

This method makes a call to a static method in my MVC site that cleans up old files and sends out emails.

This static method works FINE when I call it directly through my website.

However when calling the WCF service method from my Windows Service, the emails never get sent. The error is listed below:

Message: Failure sending mail. 
Inner Exception: Unable to connect to the remote server, a connection attempt failed because the connected host has failed to respond

I'm thinking this is a permission issue, maybe the Local Service account under which the WIndows Service is running is not authorized to send mail?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service starts with the "system" account which might not have access to your remote email server.
You can set your service to start with a user account that has credential to connect to the remote email server.

HTH,
Cabbi

Comment: That's right, at this time I'm using the LocalService. When I find out which windows user account has access to the email server, how do I set that value in my Visual Studio Windows Installer property?

In the properties window I have a dropdown with selections for:
LocalService, NetworkService, LocalSystem & User

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672072/installer-class-that-receives-parameters-used-in-the-install-method

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that

Comment: Your suggestion combined with a new binding did the trick! Thanks